# Logcat sidebar of controls like `Clear` and `Terminate Application` missing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, logcat, android-logcat, ddms

Till last time when I used Android Studio a few hours ago, I had a sidebar of controls like 'Clear' and 'Terminate Application' etc. Like this side bar in the `Run` perspective.

[image]

I was using the control to easily terminate applications. **But now it's gone**, and I don't know how to terminate my applications.

[image]

**So what should I do to get it back? Is there another easy way to terminate apps?**

***Addendum:*** I have seen this question, but I don't know how to find that DDMS perspective. And where are my controls from the Logcat gone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Came here looking for answer but figure out one myself,in case anyone needs it anyway:
Right click the Android tab (where it says Android above the Emulator/Device name), when the menu pops select 'Show toolbar' .

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio layout has changed since 2015, so for today (Android Studio 4.2.2):

The **context menu** popup of the Logcat tab (accessible through the **little gear icon** on the top right of the tab) has the option "*show toolbar*".

[image: Logcat context menu show toolbar]

This will bring back toolbar on the left side of Logcat. Hope that info will help someone someday :)